# problem with API calls with ionic capacitor http

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ssl-certificate, capacitor

i'm trying to call APIs on a cluster with a trusted cert, but this is my response:

```
6140.295ff557e4b6f594.js:1 Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: AndroidOpenSSL, class: com.android.org.conscrypt.DefaultSSLContextImpl)
    at returnResult (localhost/:915)
    at Object.win.androidBridge.onmessage (localhost/:890)
```

I'm using ionic capacitor with CapacitorHttp plugin, this is my code:

```
private apiUrl = environment.getCitta;

  async ottieniCitta() {
    try {
      this.access_token = await this.storage.get('access_token');
      const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.access_token}`,
      };

      const response = await CapacitorHttp.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: this.apiUrl,
        headers: headers,
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = response.data as any[]; 
        // Salva i dati nello storage locale
        await this.storage.set('citta', data);
      } else {
        console.error('Errore nella chiamata API:', response.status);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Errore durante la chiamata API:', error);
    }
  }
```

I want to call my APIs on the cluster